# What's better in terms of performance? Using addEventListener("click) in each element or add it to the document and differenciate them using e.target?

Tags: javascript, html

Just as I said in the title, I'm learning JS and I want my code to have the best performance possible. I saw a video in which the youtuber said that applying the addEventListener("click") to the document and using if statements to differenciate "how" activated the event is more effective and has a better performance than applying it individually

EXAMPLE

```
$document.addEventListener("click",(e)=>{
   if (e.target.matches("nav i img")){
       console.log("logrado");
       if (hamburgerMenuState == false){
           $hamburgerMenu.classList.add("left-zero");
           $hamburgerMenu.classList.remove("left-away");
           hamburgerMenuState = true;
       }
       else{
           $hamburgerMenu.classList.remove("left-zero");
           $hamburgerMenu.classList.add("left-away");
           hamburgerMenuState = false;
       }        
   }
   else if(e.target.matches("#hamburger-menu ul li a")){
       console.log("nahse")
       $hamburgerMenu.classList.remove("left-zero");
       $hamburgerMenu.classList.add("left-away");
       hamburgerMenuState = false;
   }
   else if(e.target.matches("#seccion1 #iniciarReloj")){
       $btnIniciarReloj.disabled = true;
       intervalo = setInterval(()=>{
           console.log(intervalo);
           let fecha = new Date();
           $document.getElementById("reloj").textContent = fecha.toLocaleTimeString();
       },1000)
   }
   else if(e.target.matches("#seccion1 #detenerReloj")){
       $btnIniciarReloj.disabled = false;
       clearInterval(intervalo);
       $document.getElementById("reloj").textContent = "";
   }
   else if(e.target.matches("#seccion1 #iniciarAlarma")){
       audio.play();
   }
   else if(e.target.matches("#seccion1 #detenerAlarma")){
       audio.pause();
       audio.currentTime = 0;
   }
})
```

Comment: Irrelevant in 99% of situations. Write clean, legible code first (and what that precisely means depends on the situation and project) - that's far more important.

Comment: Every time you click on the document, even if you don't click on one of the matching areas, it runs this function.  With listeners set on the specific elements, it will only run when you click on those elements.  However, I doubt you will see much if any performance difference.